# Connecting to server having same name as other server on same network

Tags: networking, linux, ssh

In my college, I have three computers connected to a same network with same name. I use SSH to connect with those computers using their IP address, but what if I want to connect to one of them using host name.

```
ssh iitz @172.23.18.100  //connecting with IP
ssh iitz @172.23.18.101
```

Now they have same user name and same host name ***iitz*** , ***HP-elite***.
how to differentiate them.

Comment: And in addition to making your private solution in `/etc/hosts`, contact your system administrator, and tell him to fix the situation with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your /etc/hosts file to make up distinguishing names:

```
172.23.18.100 hp-elite-1
172.23.18.101 hp-elite-2
172.23.18.102 hp-elite-3
```

Then you can use

```
ssh iiitz@hp-elite-2
```

If you're using Windows, it also has a hosts file, and it resides (if I remember correctly) somewhere under c:\windows\system32 (or something close to that - you can easily search for it)

Comment: OK! so if i had used ssh "iitz@hp-elite" in my case, which one of the servers would i have been connected.

Comment: That depends on what your DNS server resolves "hp-elite" to. It's possible to configure DNS servers to give out different IP addresses for the same name in a round-robin fashion (try pinging facebook or dropbox or google and look at the ip addresses that answer to see a real-world implementation of this), but it's very unlikely that this is what your DNS server would do. Usually, a single name only resolves to a single IP address.